# Swift: Convert latitude, longitude into the x,y,z coordinate in meter

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, location, coordinate-systems

```
let r: Double = 6371 + (self.locationManager.location?.altitude)!
let xPos =  r * cos((self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!) * cos((self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
```

I'm trying to convert the latitude and longitude to the x,y,z coordinate system in meter. I've searched for many conversion formulas but each one gives a different result. The above code is what i tried. I used this formula: x=(radius+altitude) * cos(altitude) * cos(longitude)
The problem is that i want it in meter, and when i try using this formula in the didUpdateLocations method, the values are not logical. The value of the x is changing with an illogical huge difference.
So i think there's something wrong in the unit of measure. I want it to be in meter. Or maybe the conversion to double is causing troubles?
Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What you need  distance?

Comment: No i need to convert latitude, longitude to x y z in meter

Comment: Don't know if your formula is correct or not but `altitude` is in meters. 6371 is the radius of the Earth, in **kilometers**